# How to extract numbers from the website

Tags: python, numbers, beautifulsoup

I've got a code:

```
import urllib.request 
from bs4 import *
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen("http://biznes.pl/waluty/profile/fixing-nbp/jen-japonia,821,0,30,profile-waluta-nbp.html"), "lxml")
price = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"cena"})
print(price)
```

The result is:

```
[<div class="cena">

                                                            3,6178

                        </div>, <div class="cena Waluta">PLN</div>, <div class="cena up"></div>]
```

I want to separate number "3,6178" to use it in further calculations. How should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you can do the following:

```
p = price[0].string.strip()
```

to get the string "3,6178"

Note, however, that you will also want to get rid of the comma to do calculations:

```
p = int(p.replace(",", ""))
```

Edit: if (as pointed out by Padraic below) 3,6178 is actually meant to represent the value 3.6178, you can make the simple modification:

```
p = float(p.replace(",", "."))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the locale into account, `36178` is not necessarily  `3,6178` depending on the locale, if you want a single element you should also use `find`:

```
In [1]: import urllib.request

In [2]: import locale

In [3]: locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')
Out[3]: 'de_DE'

In [4]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [5]: soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen("http://biznes.pl/waluty/profile/fixing-nbp/jen-japonia,821,0,30,profile-waluta-nbp.html"), "lxml")

In [6]: price = soup.find("div", {"class":"cena"})

In [7]: print(locale.atof(price.text.strip()))
3.6178
```

The site is Polish so taking the locale as [`pl_PL`](http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/pl-PL/), it would mean `3,6178` was the same as the output above, `3.6178`.